# Should a solid state hard drive make crunching work noises?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, desktop-computer

I use heavy software. 3d, mostly. I'm used to the comforting sound of a hard drive that sounds like a popcorn popper.

But, just got my first Lenovo, with a solid state hard drive. Model KXG6AZNV512G TOSHIBA to be exact.

Its making high frequency crunching noises...even in sequence with every keypress (firefox browser, 1104 memory use).

Wow.

When I use zbrush I hear buzzing with every rotation of the model.

Is this normal?

Comment: No. Desktop?  Probably the Power Supply making a noise. If under warranty, call Lenovo Support and they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

A solid state disk (SSD) has no moving parts.  Therefore, it does make any vibrations to transfer in to the air, which would result in audible sound.

It is possible that the drive's electronics are creating magnetic interference with the computer's electronics, resulting in noise.  This can come through the computers speakers and even through some of the electronics.  I have not seen this happen personally with SSDs, but have in some YouTube videos of people complaining about it.   I have seen it occur with other electronics.  I have seen some manufacturers put shielding over the drives and other parts, to prevent this.  Since this is a new laptop, it sounds more like a defect.

All this is assuming that interference is the culprit.  It could be something else.

I would contact Lenovo, or the place of purchase and either get it serviced or exchanged.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Reread my answer.   I *specifically* mentioned that it might not be the drive and that it could be just electronics.

Comment: I, also, would not rush to blame the SSD. Some electronic equipment contains switching mode power supplies or voltage regulators, and components (e.g. capacitors) can vibrate at frequencies that give rise to high-pitched audible sounds that younger people may be able to hear. I had a cheap Chinese tablet whose wall-wart power supply made a high pitched sound that my son could hear but I could not. Having said that I would also check my speakers, e.g. by turning them off or muting.

Comment: It sounds like a hard drive, except faster/higher pitch.